# Masking password input from the console, "Cannot resolve symbol 'console'"

Tags: java

So when ever I try to compile this code, I get:

java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class console
location: class java.lang.System

I don't understand why when I initiate the console object, System.console() can't be resolved...

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class User {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Console console = new System.console();

    private String userID, userPW, userPIN;
    private char[] password = new char[6];


    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserPW() {
        return userPW;
    }

    public void setUserPW(String userPW) {
        this.userPW = userPW;
    }

    public String getUserPIN() {
        return userPIN;
    }

    public void setUserPIN(String userPIN) {
        this.userPIN = userPIN;
    }

 public void setUserInfo() {
      System.out.print("Please enter your User ID : ");
      this.setUserID(input.nextLine());

      System.out.print("Please enter your Password: ");
      this.setUserPW(input.nextLine());

      this.password = console.readPassword("Enter password");
      Arrays.fill(this.password, '*');
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

It's not

```
Console console = new System.console();
```

It should be

```
Console console = System.console();
```

Answer (score 4):

you are trying to access console using System class, where console() method is static so there  is no need to put new keyword in front of System.console(), Just delete the new keyword.